# How to export Sharepoint 2013 list to SQL Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, reporting-services, sql

Suggest best possible way to add data from SharePoint 2013 list to SQL.
If the suggested option is SSIS please elaborate on how to perform the same, i am not able to find any links or video tutorials explaining the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Sid There is a documentation to achieve this using SSIS. This might help you. [SSIS Documentation Doc !](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/2/0/D20E1C5F-72EA-4505-9F26-FEF9550EFD44/SharePoint%20SSIS%20Adapters%202011.docx)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at Microsoft Flow, if you have Office 365 it's a real natural, check it out at https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/services/shared_sharepointonline/sharepoint/. For regular updates it's very good. Use SSIS if you are doing a data migration. You'll need Visual Studio Professional, check out how to create a SSIS project here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137823.aspx . Once you are started it's fairly straightforward.